# Show all products on one page in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product, products, product-collection, cms-pages

I need a page where all products should be displayed. All products from all categories, also including filters by attributes.

I have tried to use the following block

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_homepage" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

However, it doesn't work.

When I create a parent category I get nested categories and they are displayed under the `All categories` category, this is not what I need.

Please suggest a way to display all products on a single page.

Answer (score 1):

Add following line in your cms page.

```
{{block class="Vendor\Module\Block\ListProduct" name="custom.product.list" template="Vendor_Module::product/list.phtml"}}
```

Create your custom block and phtml file as given below.

> Vendor/Module/Block/ListProduct.php

```
<?php
...
...

private $productCollection;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollection
) {
    $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function getProductCollection()
{
    return $this->productCollection->create();
}
```

> Vendor/Module/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

```
$collection = $block->getProductCollection();

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    print_r($product->getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Create Module OnePageProduct**
Step 1: Create a new module named Magepow_OnePageProducts
Create the file named registration.php in the path **app/code/Magento/OnePageProducts**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Magento_OnePageProducts',
    __DIR__
);
```

Create the file named module.xml in the path
**app/code/Magento/OnePageProducts/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Magento_OnePageProducts" setup_version="2.0.0" />
</config>
```

Create the file named routes.xml in the path
**app/code/Magento/OnePageProducts/etc/frontend/routes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <!--Define a custom route with id and frontName-->
        <route frontName="magento" id="magento">
            <module name="Magento_OnePageProducts"/>
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

Create the Onepage.php file in the path
**app/code/Magento/OnePageProducts/Controller/Product/Onepage.php**

```
<?php

namespace Magento\OnePageProducts\Controller\Product;

class Onepage extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $_coreRegistry;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $coreRegistry,
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $coreRegistry;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $store = $this->_storeManager->getStore();
        $category = $this->categoryRepository->get(
            $store->getRootCategoryId()
        );

        $this->_coreRegistry->register('current_category', $category);

        $page = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $page->getLayout()->getBlock('page.main.title')->setPageTitle(__('One Page Products'));
        $page->getLayout()->getBlock('breadcrumbs')->addCrumb(
            'home',
            [
                'label' => __('Home'),
                'title' => __('Go to Home Page'),
                'link' => $store->getBaseUrl()
            ]
        )->addCrumb(
            'product-tag',
            [
                'label' => __('One Page Products'),
                'title' => __('One Page Products')
            ]
        );
        $page->getConfig()->addBodyClass('page-products');
        $page->getConfig()->getTitle()->set(__('One Page Products'));
        $page->getConfig()->setDescription(__('One Page Products'));
        $page->getConfig()->setKeywords(__('One Page Products'));
        $page->getConfig()->addRemotePageAsset($this->_url->getUrl('magento/product/onepage'), 'canonical', ['attributes' => ['rel' => 'canonical']]);

        return $page;
    }
}
```

Create the layout named **magento_product_onepage.xml**
**app/code/Magento/OnePageProducts/view/frontend/layout/magento_product_onepage.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="catalog_category_view" />
    <update handle="catalog_category_view_type_layered" />
</page>
```

Run the below commands and check.
**php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

php bin/magento cache:flush**

Answer (score 0):

**Step:-1** Call block in your cms page where you want show products.

```
{{block class="{vendorname}\{modulename}\Block\AllProductsOnePage" name="block_name" template="vendorname_modulename::product/list.phtml"}}
```

**Step:-2** Create Block **vendorname/modulename/Block/AllProductsOnePage.php** file.

```
<?php
namespace vendorname\modulename\Block;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

class AllProductsOnePage extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    private $productCollection;

    public function __construct(
        Template\Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $productCollection,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productCollection = $productCollection;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    public function getProductsCollection()
    {
        return $this->productCollection->create();
    }
}
```

**Step:-3** Create phtml **vendorname/modulename/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml** file.

```
<?php
/**
 * @var \vendorname\modulename\Block\ListProduct $block
 */
$productsCollections = $block->getProductsCollection();
foreach ($productsCollections as $productsCollection) {
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($productsCollection->getData());
}
```

After the above changes run the setup:upgrade command.
**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**